# 'I know him before I know you' or 'I've known him before I've known you'

Tags: grammar

Which one is the correct sentence?

> I know him before I know you

or

> I've known him before I've known you

Comment: Neither. *I knew him before I knew you.* Or perhaps better, *I've known him **longer than** I've known you.*

Comment: Note that *I knew him before you* and *I've known him longer than you* are also both valid and would often be used by native speakers. Those versions are potentially ambiguous (they might mean *...before **you knew** him / ...longer than **you have** known him*), but the intended sense would usually be contextually obvious (in the mind of the *speaker*, if not the addressee), so that wouldn't normally be seen as a problem at time of utterance.

Comment: Note for some learners: To Know(state) is not the same as To Meet (action). First you meet someone, then you get to know them until you feel you finally know them.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of OP's suggestions are idiomatic. Common alternatives are...

> 1: ***I knew him before I knew you***
>    and perhaps better,
>    2: ***I've known him longer than I've known you***

---

Note that...

> 1a: ***I knew him before you***
>    and
>    2a: ***I've known him longer than you***

...are also both valid and would often be used by native speakers. Those versions are potentially ambiguous (they might mean *...before **you knew him** / ...longer than **you have known him***). But the intended sense would usually be contextually obvious (in the mind of the speaker, if not the addressee), so that wouldn't normally be seen as a problem at time of utterance.

Answer (score 0):

*"I know him before I know you"* should use the past verb (**knew**).  As in:

> "I knew him before I knew you."

Other than that, both are correct.
Though, the second one could be better if written as,

> "I've known him before I knew you"

Comment: I query the correctness of **I've known him before I've known you**. Can you substantiate it?

Comment: What @RonaldSole said. That construction isn't at all idiomatic for me as a competent native (BrE) speaker.